# Can every topological space be considered as a subspace of a separable space?

Tags: general-topology

We know that subset of a separable space may not be separable.

Now is it true that any topological space can be considered as a subspace of a separable space?

Please give a hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Let $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ be a topological space, and let $p$ be any point not in $X$. Let

$$\tau'=\{U\cup\{p\}:U\in\tau\}\cup\{\varnothing\}\;;$$

then $\tau'$ is a topology on $X\cup\{p\}$ such that the relative topology on $X$ is $\tau$, and $\{p\}$ is a countable dense subset of $X\cup\{p\}$.

Of course $\langle X\cup\{p\},\tau'\rangle$ is never $T_1$, though it is $T_0$ if $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is.

Comment: @ B.M. Scott: Thank you sir! Now it directly follows from this fact that the separability is not a hereditary property.

Comment: @Anupam: It does indeed. You’re welcome!

Comment: @Brian M. Scott: Sir,I didn't understand the $T_{0}$ part. If one take $X$ with indiscreet topology, then how could $X\cup \{p\}$ be $T_{0}$?

Comment: @Alearner: I wrote that carelessly; I’ve corrected it now.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott : thank you sir, for the response.

Comment: @Alearner: You’re welcome.